# Plant identification: Is this hosta?

Tags: identification, shrubs, landscaping

Is this hosta? The flowers were actually beautiful, but seemed to harbor small bugs.

[image: hosta]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a hosta.

The somewhat heart-shaped (lanceolate or ovate) leaves with the district veins following the leaf shape is quite telling and so are the upright (in your picture bent over) scapes with the flowers towering over the greenery. Your specimen’s color pale purple is a frequent color, hosta breeds bloom typically in the white to purple. If you are lucky, yours may have had a scent, best noticeable in the evening. But that varies between cultivars.