# Is this some kind of Rhododendron?

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs, landscaping

Location: western Massachusetts

Beautiful flowers around this time of year (May).

[image: Rhododendron] ([large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC4rX.jpg))

A close-up before flowering.

[image: Pre flowering] ([large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dpnj.jpg))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a rhododendron. Yup.

Comment: Thanks. I feel kind of silly to have to ask about this one.

Comment: @RocW. No need to feel silly. We're all here to learn. And, FWIW, that last "yup" was just because there's a minimum number of characters required to post an answer.

Comment: You could add the main characteristics that made your recognize it though.

Comment: @BenceKaulics "Rhododendron are characterised by having inflorescences with scarious (dry) perulae, a chromosome number of x=13, fruit that has a septicidal capsule, an ovary that is superior (or nearly so), stamens that have no appendages, and agglutinate (clumped) pollen." (Wikipedia). Alternatively, "I know what a rhododendron looks like and that is obviously what it is." Do either of these tell you anything useful? :)

Comment: @alephzero Given how different plants can look quite similar to untrained eyes, I found answers like [this one](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/57905/26690) very helpful. Wikipedia is good, but I'm often still confused after reading its overly complete and academic descriptions. It's perhaps more useful to an expert.

Comment: @alephzero I was just trying to suggest that the answer is rather minimal and instead of a "yup" more useful information (not scientific, just what makes it you obvious) could have been added to it to reach the minimum number of characters. What obvious for you is not necessarily obvious for others. :)

Comment: @BenceKaulics I simply couldn't think of anything else to say about identifying rhododendrons. If you can think of something more useful to write about identifying Rhododendrons, please write a new answer. I would be happy to delete this answer if you write a better one.

Comment: The "false wilting" of the leaves indicates rhododendron also. The leaves look slightly wilted, regardless of watering.